# Testing HTML/CSS templates for mobile

Tags: android, iphone, html, css, blackberry

My company wants to start building mobile versions of our websites so we need to setup a test environment to make sure the front end templates look/function as they should.

We're looking to support iPhone, Blackberry, Android and Windows mobile, so we need a way to see how our HTML/CSS/JS templates will look on these devices.

So short of going out and buying one of each phone, does a simulator exist that we can install on a Windows 7 desktop where we can test our web templates?

I remember using a Blackberry emulator a few years ago but can we rely on something similar for all platforms? Briefly looking into simulating an iPhone seems to require paying $99 per year for downloading their SDK, and also this only works on an Apple computer?

A global solution that covers all platforms would be ideal. Can anyone help/provide advice?

Many thanks.

Comment: Nothing beats the source. I say get one of each phone (I mean, SOMEONE  on your team must have an iPhone and an Android right? And you can easily connect it to the local network of the computer via WiFi and test even if the files are local).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: This should be considered obsolete as it is no longer true.

I have been using the SDK's for Android, Windows Phone and a few Blackberry simulators. From what I understand, Safari's desktop browser functions so similarly to the iOs browser that you can fairly confidently use it to test (you can change to mobile user agent with in the developer menu). This is still no replacement for the actual device, the occasional issue will slip by.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

http://us.blackberry.com/developers/resources/simulators.jsp

The android sdk is great because their emulators let you test a range of device OS versions and resolutions, you are also able to change the orientation between landscape and portrait with the numpad (numlock off).

Comment: If it even was true back in 2012, it's not true anymore - buttons behave absolutely differently, css need tons of specific flags. Never use Safari, better use Simulator to test against real devices

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver 5.5 Live View in the resolutions of the devices you're working with would be a good start.